# performSegueWithIdentifier NSInvalidArgumentException after call from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, storyboard, segue

Hey together,

I am calling a void with some parameters from the AppDelegate on my main view.
This is done if a push notification is received:

```
MainViewController *mainView = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
[mainView showPushView:pushDataObject];
```

The called void @ the MainView doing some data operating stuff and after that it should load the pushView:

```
- (void)showPushView: (PFObject *)pushDataObject {
    NSLog(@"Push Data object transfered %@", pushDataObject);
    pushItem = pushDataObject;
    //All working fine to this point 
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showPushObject" sender:self];
}
```

**Now the problem is that the app is crashing at `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showPushObject" sender:self];` with this Error:**

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
'Receiver (<MainViewController: 0x145b80e0>) has no segue with identifier 'showPushObject''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2e51fe83 0x3887c6c7 0x30f656d9 0xbeb11 0xb2a23 0x1745f7 0x38d610c3 0x38d610af 0x38d639a9 0x2e4ea5b1 0x2e4e8e7d 0x2e453471 0x2e453253 0x3318d2eb 0x30d08845 0xafecd 0x38d75ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I think that there is a problem because I call the void from the AppDelegate, am I right?

Those anyone know a fix for that problem?

Thanks a lot!
Best regards from Germany :)

**P.S.** If I call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showPushObject" sender:self];` with a button or something on the MainViewController all working fine... :/

Comment: So, it works when you perform the `segue` from a method within the view controller, but in this case you're trying to perform the `segue` from the `appDelegate`?  And `mainView` is a `@property` of your `appDelegate`?

Comment: @nhgrif yes that's right!

Comment: In that case, your question has already been answered.

Comment: @nhgrif But actually I don't know how to fix the problem because my storyboard is already loaded at the app launch in the AppDelegate...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line:

```
MainViewController *mainView = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
```

because it means that the `mainView` instance doesn't have a storyboard (so it can't have any segues).

When you run it from a button the controller instance must have been created from a storyboard.

So, to fix, load the storyboard and instantiate `mainView` from it. Then the segue will work.

---

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard4Inch = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard4Inch" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *mainViewController = [storyboard4Inch instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainViewController"];
[mainViewController showPushView:pushDataObject];
```

Comment: Can you actually show me how to load the storyboard and instantiate mainView from it? :)

Comment: `UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:bundle:` to load the storyboard and then `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` for the view controller (which needs to have an identifier set.

Comment: You should be able to get the storyboard from `self.window.rootViewController.storyboard` too. In the app delegate where you should have a reference to the window.

Comment: Unfortunately I am already doing this at my app launch:
`UIStoryboard *Storyboard4Inch = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard4Inch" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *initialViewController = [Storyboard4Inch instantiateInitialViewController];` - I use this to have different storyboards for different screen sizes...

Comment: Ok, so you have a reference to the storyboard like that, and you can instantiate any view controller with an identifier.

Comment: Okay I tried this: `UIStoryboard *Storyboard4Inch = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard4Inch" bundle:nil];
    [Storyboard4Inch instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainViewController"];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showPushObject" sender:self];`
But it's still crashing...

Answer (score 0):

In order for the segue to work, you need to have the storyboard loaded in the mainView when you start it that way. Try instead something like this:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *firstViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"kYourMainViewControllerIdentifier"];
self.window.rootViewController = firstViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Remember to give an identifier to your root view controller and change it in this piece of code.